# Eclipse GitLab clone problem "Malformed input or unmappable characters"

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, https, gitlab, git-clone

When I try to clone [my GitLab repo](https://gitlab.com/gerib/userscripts) from within Eclipse (2019-09, Kubuntu 21.04) via `https://gitlab.com/gerib/userscripts.git` I get:

[image: Eclipse Git clone problem]

The only "abnormal" characters I see in the mentioned script are JS string delimiter backticks.

`git clone https://gitlab.com/gerib/userscripts.git` in *Konsole* works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what's the problem after importing the project into Eclipse and recognizing that the files in the `/stackexchange` folder are not shown in the *Project Explorer* view. In the *Git Repositories* view → *Working Tree* they are shown as:

[image: "wrong" filename characters]

This is bad since I just used the Unicode [Dash](https://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/ndash) "–" (U+2013 , Win: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, X11: <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, HTML: `&ndash;`).

*Dolphin* shows the filenames properly.

An `ls` in *Konsole* shows them as:

```
'StackExchange '$'\342\200\223'' Expand Hidden Comments.user.js'
'StackExchange '$'\342\200\223'' Tweak UI.user.js'
```

Well, Unicode 1.0.0 was only published recently in 1991...

Comment: Make sure your JGit/EGit is up to date and check whether the issue can be reproduced in Eclipse: create a file with a dash in the filename, commit it, delete it and then do a _Replace With > HEAD Revison_. If yes, make sure it has been reported to Eclipse EGit along with the Git configuration (e.g. because of [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.22.0#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreprecomposeUnicode) etc.) and information about your file system.

Comment: @howlger EGit (5.13.0.202109080827) was up to date. I did a _Check for Updates_ today before. Do you want me to file an Eclipse bug report in case an error occurs during the procedure you suggest if there is none yet?

Comment: Yes, please make sure it has been reported if it is not a Git misconfiguration (I do not know how Git handles Unicode characters, but I assume that a committed filename has to be restored from Git again).